# getting values of DataTable column and putting it into new datatable C# using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I Have a datable that I use to store ingredient recipes. I have some code that finds if there are similar ingredient names and if there are, I then sum up the weight and add it to the table.

Now i want to be able to add some few other columns that also exist in the table.

Here is what i currently have

```
protected DataTable cleanDataTable(DataTable dt)
{

    var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Ingredients"))
         .Select(g =>
         {
             var row = dt.NewRow();
             row.ItemArray = new object[]
                    {
                        g.Key, 
                        g.Sum(r => double.Parse(r.Field<string>("KG")))


                    };
             return row;
         }).CopyToDataTable();

    dt = result;
    return dt;
}
```

I have the following columns, `BakerP`, `FlourP`, `BatchP`, how can i get the value of each column and save it into the datatable using the code below with Linq?

Comment: Does your current code work?  Also, you say "using the function below", but there is no function below those words.

Comment: the new DataTable will have **less** rows than the original one (due to GroupBy), but you also want to `get the value of these column and save it into the data table`? That's impossible, unless you have some rule to pick one of rows in each group.

Comment: Are `BakerP`, `FlourP`, and `BatchP` meant to be numeric values?  Do you want to sum them?  Or group on them?  If you're grouping, grouping by and summing (or other aggregate functions, like Average or Max) are your only options for a column.

Comment: i mean the function above typo, this code does work but only includes the values from 2 columns not the rest.

Comment: @user2988901 did you notice my previous comment? If you want to include other columns (which may have different values in the same group), you have to provide some rule to **just pick one**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what data types `BakerP`, `FlourP`, or `BatchP` are, so the following just lists some options:

If the fields are numeric, and you want to summarize them like you did the weight, you would do the same kind of thing you did with the weight in order to add those fields to the row :

```
 var row = dt.NewRow();
 row.ItemArray = new object[]
   {
      g.Key, 
      g.Sum(r => double.Parse(r.Field<string>("KG"))),
      g.Sum(r => double.Parse(r.Field<string>("BakerP"))), // assuming this is also a number saved as a string
      // etc.
   };
 return row;
```

If they are not numeric, or you don't want to summarize them, you can group on them, as you did with Ingredients:

```
.GroupBy(r => new { 
     Ingredients = r.Field<string>("Ingredients"), 
     BakerP = r.Field<string>("BakerP"),
     FlourP = r.Field<string>("FlourP"),
     BatchP = r.Field<string>("BatchP")
 })
.Select(g =>
     {
         var row = dt.NewRow();
         row.ItemArray = new object[]
            {
                g.Key.Ingredients, 
                g.Key.BakerP,
                g.Key.FlourP,
                g.Key.BatchP,
                g.Sum(r => double.Parse(r.Field<string>("KG")))
            };
         return row;
     }).CopyToDataTable();
```

Or you can mix and match, grouping on one field while summarizing another.

The key thing, though: *since you're using GroupBy, all the fields in your output need to either be part of what you group by, or be summarized in some way (with .Sum() or .Average() or .Max() or .First(), etc.)*  So if you want these additional fields in your output, you need to decide which way you want to handle them.

Comment: Thanks that is what i was looking for, I'm kinda new to LINQ so the explanation is appreciated.